# Django: QuerySet evaluation

Tags: django

**Django 1.11.2**

In the example, below I have got a QuerySet "arts".

I iterate through it in the view (that list comprehension).
The transmit the queryset to the template.
Ant in the template I again iterate through it in the for loop.

In the documentation I can read that QuerySets are evaluated in case of iteration.

This is the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

But I organized a log file for PostgreSQL. 
And try to control database hits:

tail -f postgresql-2017-07-20_120840.log

Well, there is only one hit in this case.

Could you comment on this. As far as I can understand the QuerySet was evaluated when that list comprehension worked. Then it remembered it state: it is already evaluated. And in the template it just worked without evaluation.

Could you comment on this: am I right. If I'm wrong, then why only one evaluation happened?

**views.py**

```
class AsciiView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        arts = Art.objects.all()

        if arts:
            points = [(art.lat, art.lon) for art in arts if (art.lat and art.lon)]
        else:
            points = []

        return render(request,
                      "ascii_chan/ascii_chan.html",
                      {"arts": arts,
                       "points": points})
```

**ascii_chan.html**

```
{% for art in arts %}
    <div class="art">
        <h2 class="art-title">{{ art.title }}  {{ art.created }}</h2>

        <pre class="art-body">{{ art.art }}</pre>
    </div>
{% empty %}
    <div>Nothing so far.</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, isn't that what the documentation says? It's evaluated when it's first iterated.

Comment: I understood this point of the documentation as: one select is performed for the whole loop (not an individual select for each iteration). I thought that when a QuerySet is iterated again, a new select is performed. If QuerySet remembers its state, it must have an attribute "evaluated" or something. I'm studying the source code of the QuerySet now. And I can't find where it keeps its state. Could you help me here?

Comment: Well, a QuerySet seems really to remember its state in the attribute _result_cache.